# Failed to register thread

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I ran into a problem with my application deployed to Cloud Run and written in Kotlin and Spring Boot. I see `Failed to register thread`  error message Intermittently and application stops responding.

Cloud Run is configured to always allocate CPU.

I have been trying to find information online but without any success. Has anyone of you come across this error message?

[Cloud Run logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHd7K.png)

Thank you in advance for any clues!

I have tried to enable "Always allocate CPU" as the application uses asynchronous processing and official documentation states that if CPU is not always allocated then asynchronous processing might not work.

Comment: 1) Each of the error messages has the same timestamp. If your app is suffering from memory pressure, you are not giving the app CPU time to recover as it appears your code is in a tight loop. Implement [Exponential Backoff and Retry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) logic in your code. 2) The return code is `-1`. Call another error routine to get the actual error number/message. 3) I guess you have not allocated enough memory to the Cloud Run instance. Resize the instance larger and retry after correctly implementing suggestion 1.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.